# How can I pass values from a functional component through a React Router Link to another functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I pass values from my `ResultItem.js` component, to my `Result.js` component using React Router's `Link` component?

ResultItem.js

```
export default function ResultItem({ result }) {
//desctructure the result elements
const {
    title,
    type,
    id,
    publisher,
    volume,
    issue,
    page_number,
    year_published,
} = result;

return (
    <>
        <div className="card grey lighten-4" style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
            <span className="badge green white-text">{type}</span>
            <h5>{title}</h5>
            <h6>Publisher: {publisher}</h6>
            <h6>Volume: {volume}</h6>
            <h6>Issue: {issue}</h6>
            <h6>Page Number: {page_number}</h6>
            <h6>Year Published: {year_published}</h6>

            <div>
                <Link
                    to={`/${id}`}
                    className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue"
                >
                    Read More
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);

}
```

Result.js

```
export default function Result({ title }) {
return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <h5>
                More information about that thing you just clicked on will be on this
                page.
            </h5>
            <h1>title = {title}</h1>
        </div>
    </>
);

}
```

App.js

```
<Route path="/:id" component={Result} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{ 
       pathname: `/item/${item.id}`,
       state: {id: item.id}
}}>
```

Later you call: `{id.id}` in Result

Does it works?

Comment: No unfortunately not, that just throws an undefined error for  `id` inside of the `Results.js`.

Comment: What do you mean by `call: {id.id} in Result` ?

Comment: If You add - 
const { match } = props;
let id = match.params;

It's possible to called id by {id.id}